# get scaling status using DocumentClient.ReadOfferAsync

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, scaling, status

I am automatically scaling my cosmosDb using azure.DocumentClient. I want to skip if there is existing scaling in progress and wait for 1 minute and try again.

i have suggestion here "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput" that I can use DocumentClient.ReadOfferAsync and see the status of the scaling.

I dont understand what property of the return type I should look for in the return type?

Answer (score 0):

The V3 SDK client provides a way to know the status as part of the `ThroughputResponse`'s property [IsReplacePending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.throughputresponse.isreplacepending?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_ThroughputResponse_IsReplacePending).

This is obtained when `ReadThroughputAsync` is called on the Container:

```
Container container = database.GetContainer(containerId);
var throughputResponse = await simpleContainer.ReadThroughputAsync();
```

This property is [checking for a particular Header in the response](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Throughput/ThroughputResponse.cs#L80). If you are using the V2 SDK you can probably check the headers in the `ResourceResponse` and look for the same headers to know if the upgrade is still pending.

```
public bool? IsReplacePending
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Headers.GetHeaderValue<string>(WFConstants.BackendHeaders.OfferReplacePending) != null)
        {
            return Boolean.Parse(this.Headers.GetHeaderValue<string>(WFConstants.BackendHeaders.MinimumRUsForOffer));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```